# Need help in optimizing the query in ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, query-optimization

I have some 30,000 records in my Raw_deals table and some raw_cities table has some 30 records and each deal is linked with some 5-8 cities.

Now i want to fetch any random deal within some specific cities.

List of those cities can be fetched like this:

```
@raw_cities = RawCity.where('disabled = ?', 0).map(&:id)
```

Now i need a deal. I wrote a query but its taking too much time.

```
@raw_deal = RawDeal.order("RAND()").find(:first,:joins=>[:raw_cities], :conditions=>["raw_cities.id IN (?)",@raw_cities])
```

Comment: you may try to random between randam date ranges, but you will always have trouble with performance if you want to apply a random algorithm in a table that is always growing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `order("RAND()")` is probably what's slowing your query down, and since you're only looking for one single deal, you can use a combination of `limit` and `offset` to simulate a random order.

Try something like this:

```
@raw_deal = RawDeal.offset(rand(RawDeal.count)).
                    joins(:raw_cities).
                    where(raw_cities: @raw_cities).
                    first
```